# Docker - port not published, but still available?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container here which seems to not have any ports published:

[image: screenshot of docker ps]

the problem is: it still is available under 8911 (which it is supposed to be)!
How can I figure out why this is like that and why there are no ports shown?
The Docker containers are managed by caprover (https://caprover.com/)

any idea would be great!

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Please post text as text. The image is unreadable.

Comment: How have you determined that it's available?